# How to add class after more

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Hello I have a post in wordpress and I use the_excerpt function to hide some text but I want to display it after click read more without reloading page and I need also to add to this hidden text a class and style how can i do it?

```
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'oferta', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1 ) );
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();                                        
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $the_query->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
?>  
<div class="col-sm-6">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>   
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'oferta', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1 ) );
// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();                                        
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $the_query->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
?>  
<div class="col-sm-6">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<span><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span><span class="read-more">Readmore</span>
<span style="display:none"><?php the_content(); ?></span>
</div>   
<script>
  $(".read-more").on("click",function(){
      $(this).prev("span").hide();
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).next("span").show();
  });
</script>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gnd6a/)

Comment: It doesn't work at all and when I use excerpt and content it duplicate all of content.

Comment: @user3211948 Edited the post. check it. Also updated JSFiddle link as demo.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to put an event listener on your 'Read more' text that toggles the display of the remaining text. I could not figure out what your _excerpt function looks like, so I couldn't make any specific recommendations, but a general pattern for it is like so:

CSS

```
<style>
   #teaser { color: blue; cursor: pointer; }
   #hiddenText { display: none; }
</style>
```

HTML

```
 <div>
 <h1>My Title Here</h1>
 <div id="myBlurb">
    <span id="teaser">Read More....</span>
    <span id="hiddenText">Here is some text that is now showing</span>
</div>    
</div>
```

And the JQuery

```
<script>
$('#teaser').click( function(){
    $('#hiddenText').toggle();
})
</script>
```

Since you tagged the question with 'JQuery', I assume you can use that library. In WordPress I believe you have the ability to add custom JS/JQuery. You can construct a script that simply targets the IDs or classes of the existing output of your PHP code. Hope this helps.

Comment: But I have some text at start and then have excerpt and it should works like this: When I click on read more it should display all of content.

Comment: Let's say all content is contained in the div with ID="myBlurb". You could then add to your JQuery script the line `$("#teaser").toggle();` This would hide the 'Read More...' text. If you have additional children under #myBlurb you could also toggle them by doing `$("#myBlurb").children().toggle();` If you have a deeply nested child tree, use `.find()` instead of `.children()`... Take advantage of the chaining in JQuery to do VERY powerful stuff. https://api.jquery.com/